# Estilo do Bootstrap datetime não funciona corretamente

Tags: css, bootstrap-3, datetime, plugin

Bom dia, primeiramente já vi pesquisei várias possíveis soluções para esse problema aqui no site, mas o erro que ele está me dando é diferente dos que eu encontrei por aqui, o arquivo está puxando uma formatação estranha, e não consigo achar qual elemento devo alterar a cor pra que ele fique como deveria ser:

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja no console se algumas das dependências, principalmente css não foram encontradas e/ou teste em outro navegador.

Comment: Ele está encontrando tudo certinho, já verifiquei nos meus estilos que alteram o Bootstrap em algumas coisas, mas não tem nada que chegue perto de modificar o datetimepicker, e também ja testei no chrome, firefox e no edge, sempre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Poste os trechos relevantes de código e se possível um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). É pouco dificil dizer o que acontece sem ver nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, estava usando o modelo 'bootflat' para construir o painel, e esse modelo possui alguns estilos no css que modificam certos plugins como jquery-ui e o datepicker, mudei pro AdminLTE e funcionou corretamente!
Obrigado ela atenção!

Comment: Marque a sua resposta ;)